# opendir php error with variables

Tags: php, function, opendir

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
<?php
    $user = $fgmembersite->UserFullName();
    $handle = opendir('/users/$user/');
?>
```

This is the error message:

```
opendir(/app/$user/) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes to evaluate variables

```
$handle = opendir("/users/$user/");
```

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't in a developer's vocabulary. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: then the directory doesn't exist, OR if it does then you are probably looking at a permissions issue

Comment: `/users` is going to be relative to the root. What you probably want is `opendir("users/$user/")`

Comment: nevermind I figured it out and your solution helped me a lot wanovak. Thanks :)

Comment: yes the directory didn't exist because I had a "/" which pointed it to the root directory of my server not the directory I was working in

Answer (score 1):

In single quotes $user will not be interpreted as a variable - in double quotes it will be try opedir("/users/$user")

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$handle = opendir("/users/$user/");
```